# Creating a track object with track_from_file method in pyechonest

Tags: python, audio-player, echonest

I am new to python. I am trying to use `track_from_file` method in [pyechonest](http://echonest.github.io/pyechonest/index.html) to create a track object. This is the code I wrote:

```
from pyechonest import config
from pyechonest.track import track_from_file
config.ECHO_NEST_API_KEY = "KRZG4XOVUQRKI45DP"
f = open("ShayneWard-NoPromises.mp3")
t = track_from_file(f, 'mp3')
```

But this is not working. I got an `EchoNestIOError`. This is the full error Traceback that i got.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyechonest/track.py", line 243, in track_from_file 
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyechonest/track.py", line 331, in track_from_md5 
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyechonest/track.py", line 209, in _profile 
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyechonest/util.py", line 257, in callm pyechonest.util.
EchoNestIOError: Echo Nest Unknown Error
```

Can anyone tell me what have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried passing `force_upload=True` to `track_from_file()` to skip the md5 step and force an upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It seems that the upload does not take place through the proxy server of my university network which uses NAT.